# Help with Lubuntu switching sound output

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I installed Lubuntu 15.10, all is fine. Much faster than Ubuntu, I like the minimalist interface, etc. I plug my Skullcandy Slayer (Slyr) USB headphones in, and nothing is changed. The output remains my two analog speakers.

I then tried using the 3.5 jack with my headphones, and still nothing. Audio continues playing through the 2 external speakers.

I tried xfce4-mixer and pavucontrol (pulseaudio), as well as tinkering around in alsamixer, but to no avail. I'd be fine losing my EQ if I need to use the 3.5 jack, but the same USB headphones worked flawlessly on Ubuntu 15.10... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select Pulseaudio Volume Control from the Sound and Video menu, you can go to the Configuration tab and disable Built-in Audio, then pick the appropriate output from Profile under your headset. If your headset isn't listed on the Configuration page...different problem.

Comment: Wow. My gpu's hdmi out was "unplugged" in the config menu, which I assumed meant disabled, but no. Once I disabled that and my external speakers, voila, sound! Thanks!

Comment: Figuring out how to get a headset to work was the hardest part of setting up Lubuntu for a family member! Glad it helped.

Comment: I ended up switching to Manjaro. I've always preferred Arch over Ubuntu anyway, but now I know how to use the xfce mixer!